# Gas Emulation Question

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, emulator

I am EXTREMELY new to circuit/circuit board diagrams.  I am trying to design a Gas Detector emulator that has dip switches for addressing each board, a low voltage control with low power led, and a potentiometer to register the high and low gas with LED's.  My questions is, how do you determine the resistor size that a controller is looking for to identify the high or low gas? The company that make the gas detector and controller will not release their information.

[image: Circuit Design example]

Comment: which resistor in the diagram?

Comment: please add a link to the source of the schematic diagram

Comment: The two resistors on the far right after the potentiometer R19 and R20.  I do not have a source for the schematic other than myself.  I am designing it, well trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only chemical (vapor) sensors I know of use an electrochemical cell architecture, so it’s not as simple as substituting with a resistor. These sensors seem to work more like equivalent to two variable current sources, one between the working electrode and the counter electrode (which current correlates with the gas concentration), and another between the reference electrode and counter electrode (which current tracks another electrochemical cell not exposed to the gas). We establish a reference current through the reference cell, and use a TIA to integrate the charge output from the sense cell. Like most sensors, its output is not necessarily linear, and depends somewhat on other physical factors like temperature. That’s why they have a reference cell included, essentially the sensor lets the controller perform a kind of A/B comparison between its two identical cells, and if there’s a difference between the one that is sealed and the one that is exposed to the air, then that would indicate presence of the gas.

Additionally, since there is often some temperature-dependent nonlinearity, I would expect there would be a temperature sensor (like an RTD perhaps) to measure the ambient air temperature near the sensor. You might have to determine whether that’s part of what you have to emulate or not, depending on the scope of what you’re trying to test here.

A resistor by itself just isn’t enough to emulate an electrochemical sensor. You need to find the datasheet for the actual sensor that you are trying to emulate, and ideally that datasheet (or an applications note) would include a “typical” driving circuit provided by the sensor manufacturer. That would be the place to begin determining what kind of circuitry you would need to make an emulated substitute sensor.